# how to resolve loadAnimation symbol in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm working on a Android Studio Project and my application is crashing whenever I try load a fragment with an animation. Here is my code:

```
package com.amnamughal.stockapp;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class WelcomeNote extends AppCompatActivity {
private ImageView IM;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.note_welcome);
```

The loadAnimation won't work. it says that cannot resolve symbol loadAnimation.

```
    IM = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
    Animation myanim = new AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.transition);
    IM.startAnimation(myanim);
}}
```

Help me guys..!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to make new instance of AnimationUtils. 
Update your code by removing new keyword

```
IM = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
    Animation myanim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.transition);
    IM.startAnimation(myanim);
```